# Sharepoint and SQL driven ComboBox

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

Is there a comboxBox web part out the box in SharePoint 2010 that can be loaded from a SQL table and then be used to pass and parameter to a intergrated Reporting Service report?